# Number of distinct years referenced in a document using python

Tags: python

I want to find the total number of years(which is simply an integer of four digits) referenced in a document, which is given as a normal string input using python. Can this be done without using Regex?

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex? And why did you tag this question with regex if you want a non-regex answer?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Though regex is probably more efficient. Your question is however way too broad (unless you actually only wanted a "Yes / No" answer) and shows no research effort. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but to hard - you should prepare list with all years, than split string by words and compare each word with list elements. Regex is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

I mean anything you can do with regex you can do without it.

My method below.

```
Def find_years(s):
    return [ycandidate for ycandidate in filter(len == 4, s.split()) if ycandidate.isdigit()]
```

Edit: you probably should just use regex for this though, it can seem complicated, but its well worth learning.